# Stay in the same line after the response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Stay in the same line after the response.
Every comment a user makes, I go straight to the top of the page, it's annoying and not resting.

```html
 <form method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="index.php" id="postform" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000" id="imagePreview">
<div>
<textarea class="text" id="text" cols="40" rows="4" name="image_text" placeholder="בחר תמונה וספר לנו משהו.."></textarea>
</div>
<div>
<input class="file" type="file" name="image" id="file" onchange="return fileValidation()"/>
<label for="file"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i>בחר תמונה..</label>
<h5 id="demo"></h5>
</div>
<div>
<button type="submit" class="button2" name="upload" id="submit1" onclick="move()"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>תגובה</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Show us all the relevant code and please explain further.

Comment: Do you mean that after page reload you want to  stay on the same  scroll position which was before reloading?

Comment: there are too many tags with no relevant/supportive code. I for one, have no idea what the question is about.

Comment: I believe that OP's problem is that submitting the form causes page to reload

Comment: "Do you mean that after page reload you want to stay on the same scroll position which was before reloading? – Pasha 15 mins ago " *****yes!

Comment: Exactly what you said.
I do not want to go back up every time after a new comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are talking about position on page, you can try next variant. 
Save the position to localStorage:

```
   $(window).scroll(function() {
      localStorage.scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
   });
```

and on document load, make scroll to that position:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     var position = localStorage.scrollPosition;
     if (position != 'undefined') {
        $(window).scrollTop(position);
     }
  });
```